# Importing SRFIs in a Chicken Scheme module

Tags: module, chicken-scheme, srfi

I wonder why this doesn't work:

```
(module testModule (sayHello)
  (import chicken scheme)

  (define (sayHello)
    (format #t "Hello\n")))
```

When I launch this file with `csi` it say:

> Warning: reference to possibly unbound identifier `format' in:

But [here](http://wiki.call-cc.org/SRFI-conformance) is written that the `srfi-28` (where `format` is) is builtin. Indeed if I try this...

```
(module testModule (sayHello)
  (import chicken scheme)
  (use srfi-28)

  (define (sayHello)
    (format #t "Hello\n")))
```

...it says:

> Error: (import) during expansion of (import ...) - cannot import from undefined module: srfi-28

Why? What can I do to create a module which use the `SRFI 28`?

I also tried to install the srfi-28 via `chicken-install` but rightly the egg does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mea culpa, the problem is that doesn't exist the unit `srfi-28`.
I simply solved importing `extras` unit which implements the `format` function.

```
(module testModule (sayHello)
  (import chicken scheme)
  (use extras)

  (define (sayHello)
    (format #t "ciao")))
```